# I need to copy value (not formula) from "Regular Tournament" to "Score Input-Flights" without using Select and Paste Value. Is there a simple formula?

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I'm looking for a simple way to copy values only (omitting formulas) from one sheet to another without using `.Select` and `PasteSpecial.Values`.  I have hundreds of sections of code
like this one that need modification.  I've searched the web but can't find anything that works.

```
Sheets("Regular Tournament").Select
Range("B22:B221").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Score Input-Flights").Select
Range("D13").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a simple idea (in VBA):

```
Destination_Range.Value = Source_Range.Value
```

In your case:

```
Sheets("Score Input-Flights").Range("D13:D212").Value = Sheets("Regular Tournament").Range("B22:B221").Value
```

In regular Excel it's even simpler: just use this formula:

```
='Regular Tournament'!A1
```

Comment: At risk of sounding dumb, how and where do I define the destination and source ranges?

Comment: @CharlesLangston: No problem, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Maybe not so dumb after all.  I got it.  Thanks for your help.  Problem solved!!